# только месяц и год в Datepicker jQuery Ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Требуется настроить календарь так чтобы в нем можно было выбрать из выпадающего списка только месяц и только год, без выбора дня.
Выбор месяца и года это:

```
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
```

Суть в том что нужно убрать область где отображаются дни.
Или посоветуйте другой календарь с данными возможностями.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker_reportPdf_month").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        });  
 </script>

<style type="text/css"> 
    div.ui-datepicker_reportPdf_month {
        font-size: 12px;
        width:200px;
        }
</style>

    <input type="text" id="datepicker_reportPdf_month" />
```

Comment: @splash58, можно `showButtonPanel: true` добавить, чтобы кнопка Done появилась. Комментирую сюда, а то сообщение скрыто :)

Comment: да, наверное. Еще вот тут можно посмотреть http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only

Comment: @splash58 сделайте сообщение с ссылкой из коммита и вашим ответом.   чтобы я мог отметить как верный ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table class="ui-datepicker-calendar" style="display:none">
```

или добавьте это в описание класса

Чтобы появилась кнопка Done, можно установить showButtonPanel: true (спасибо Visman)

Comment: Дело в том что у меня несколько календарей. И есть такие которые используют дни. А класс у меня для всех один.

Comment: !) вы можете менять описание класса на нужных страницах, либо менять свойство таблицы у нужных фрагментов с помощью js

Comment: @splash58, в таком варианте невозможно выбрать месяц/год, выборка там срабатывает только на клике по дню календаря.

Comment: Упс :) не подумал

Answer (score 1):

мне показалось проще использовать такой велосипед
(при котором кнопки можно не показывать, но нет и отмены)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#datepicker_reportPdf_month").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
          try {
              $(inst.dpDiv).addClass("calendar-off");
          }
          catch (err) {
              console.log("beforeShow: " + err);
          }
      },
      onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
          try {
              var date = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1);
              $(this).datepicker("setDate", date);
          }
          catch (err) {
              console.log("onClose: " + err);
          }
      },
    });
  })
  </script>
```